# Difference between: getPathSegments().get(1) and / vs getLastPathSegment()

Tags: android, path, uri, android-contentprovider

I've seen both being used for getting the ID in a content provider.

```
String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
```

Is there a difference? and if so, is one better / better practice than the other?

Or in which situation would you use one and not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a difference?

They are only the same if there are exactly 2 path segments. For a `Uri` with `/a/path/that/looks/like/this/1`, `get(1)` will not equal `getLastPathSegment()`.

> and if so, is one better / better practice than the other?

Use the one that works. In the situation where both work, use whichever one expresses your meaning better. And, if you can't decide, flip a coin.

(FWIW, I would use `getLastPathSegment()`, as usually my meaning is "get me the ID, which appears at the end of the `Uri`")